# Why I can't send embed messages to my discord bot?

Tags: java, discord, embed

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot. Unfortunately, I ran into a problem where I can't send embedded messages specifically "event.getChannel().sendMessage(***embed.build()***).queue();" this line of code is not working. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {

    public String prefix = "!";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");

        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "test")){
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Title");
            embed.setDescription("This is the Embed Description");
            embed.addField("Embed Field 1", "Field", false);
            embed.setFooter("Bot created by toMar?s");
            //event.getMessage().reply("This bot is working!").queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("This bot is working!").queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the **.sendMessage()** to **.sendMessageEmbeds()**. Probably because .sendMessage() needs some type of character sequence but I did not provide that.